# DataReader with Multiple Row

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to use the DataReader to grab data from a MS ACCESS Database and then using the items in the datareader to do some calculations. This is what I'm doing with one row.

```
Dim dataRead As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = dataCom1.ExecuteReader
    If (dataRead.Read() = True) Then
        x = dataReader.Item("x")
        y = dataReader.Item("y")
        z = dataReader.Item("z")
    End If
```

I'm trying to do the same with multiple rows that are retrieved at random. At the moment I have this:

```
Dim dataRead2 As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = dataCom2.ExecuteReader
    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        If (dataRead2.Read() = True) Then
            a(i) = dataRead2.Item("z")
            b(i) = dataRead2.Item("y")
            c(i) = dataRead2.Item("x")
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
```

Whenever I run it I get an error.

I get the error "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the line a(i)`"

Comment: What error are you getting?  How is `descarray` declared?

Comment: descarray is declared as Descarray() As String. I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the line descarray(i)

Comment: Can you try `Dim Descarray(4) As String`

Comment: Does the first section work, but the second doesn't? What's the error? I don't see dataCon being opened in the second block.

Comment: Though if the connection was not open, `.Read()` should not return `True`

Comment: @MikeChristensen Do we know that statement is even being evaluated? I'm not clear on where the error is occurring (or what it is, even)

Comment: @Dan - He said the error was `Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the line descarray(i)`

Comment: @MikeChristensen Ahh, I didn't even see that comment somehow.

Comment: @Fulgurite - No problem, I've added it as an answer.  This might be my first VB.NET answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your array is declared, but not with any specific dimensions.  You should declare it as:

```
Dim Descarray(4) As String
```

Which will hold 5 strings *(0...4)*

You can also use:

```
ReDim Descarray(5)
```

After the array has already been declared.